# Comparing a file against whitelist regex (with special characters)

Tags: regex, shell, sed, grep

I have two files, one the whitelist file(which has whitelisted call-stacks) and the other a call-stack file under test. Example contents:

```
Call stack: [thread] | object 1.0 | object 2.0 | object 3.0 | ...... | malloc
Call stack: [thread] | object 1.1 | object 2.1 | object 3.1 | ...... | malloc
Call stack: [thread] | object 1.2 | object 2.2 | object 3.2 | ...... | malloc
Call stack: [thread] | object 1.3 | object 2.3 | object 3.3 | ...... | malloc
```

Now I get a test-file with the following contents

```
Call stack: [thread] | object 1.0 | object 2.0 | * | ...... | malloc
Call stack: [thread] | object 1.1 | * | * | ...... | malloc
Call stack: [thread] | * | object 2.2 | object 3.2 | ...... | malloc
Call stack: [thread] | object 1.3 | object 2.3 | * | ...... | malloc
```

I want an algo such that if these two files are compared against each other, it returns a true stating that files are the same. i.e test-file has no call-stacks outside the whitelist file.

I understand that a while-loop with a grep on regex should do the tricks, the problem is when I tried that I am facing issues probably due to special characters in the call-stack.

**CONSTRAINTS** : Need to use only shell.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is your reason for the restriction to only use the shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no regular expressions involved, you can try the `-F` option of `grep`:

```
grep -xvFf whitelist testfile
```